# How to display data like this in laravel

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

This query it's worked for now.

```
$konfHistory = DB::table('t_history_cuti as hc')
        ->leftjoin('m_detail_organisasi as do', 'do.nik_staff', '=', 'hc.nik')
        ->join('m_karyawan as kary', 'kary.nik', '=', 'hc.nik')
        ->join('m_rumah_sakit as rs', 'rs.kd_rs', '=', 'kary.kd_rs')
        ->join('m_jabatan as jab', 'jab.kd_jabatan', '=', 'kary.kd_jabatan')
        ->join('m_unit as unit', 'unit.kd_unit', '=', 'kary.kd_unit')
        ->where('hc.kd_rs', $kdRS)
        ->where('do.koreksi', false)
        ->where('do.nik_penanggung_jawab', $nik)
        ->select('hc.*', 'kary.nik', 'kary.nm_karyawan', 'jab.nm_jabatan', 'rs.nm_rs', 'unit.nm_unit')
        ->get();
```

But i wanna show all data from t_history_cuti where status = '2' too, without duplicate data from above query.

This is a display of the data above:
[image: display data for now]

And this is the data expectation that I want:
[image: my expectation]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `->where('hc.status', '2')` ?

Comment: if I add it it will narrow the data displayed. not all data from the history_cuti table with status = '2' is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved, using union.

```
$query = DB::table('t_history_cuti as hcU')
->join('m_karyawan as kary', 'kary.nik', '=', 'hcU.nik')
->join('m_rumah_sakit as rs', 'rs.kd_rs', '=', 'kary.kd_rs')
->join('m_jabatan as jab', 'jab.kd_jabatan', '=', 'kary.kd_jabatan')
->join('m_unit as unit', 'unit.kd_unit', '=', 'kary.kd_unit')
->select('hcU.*', 'kary.nik', 'kary.nm_karyawan', 'jab.nm_jabatan', 'rs.nm_rs', 'unit.nm_unit')
->where('hcU.kd_rs', $kdRS)
->where('hcU.status', '=', '2');

$konfHistory = DB::table('t_history_cuti as hc')
->leftjoin('m_detail_organisasi as do', 'do.nik_staff', '=', 'hc.nik')
->join('m_karyawan as kary', 'kary.nik', '=', 'hc.nik')
->join('m_rumah_sakit as rs', 'rs.kd_rs', '=', 'kary.kd_rs')
->join('m_jabatan as jab', 'jab.kd_jabatan', '=', 'kary.kd_jabatan')
->join('m_unit as unit', 'unit.kd_unit', '=', 'kary.kd_unit')
->where('hc.kd_rs', $kdRS)
->where('do.koreksi', false)
->where('do.nik_penanggung_jawab', $nik)
->select('hc.*', 'kary.nik', 'kary.nm_karyawan', 'jab.nm_jabatan', 'rs.nm_rs', 'unit.nm_unit')
->union($query)
->where('hc.nik', '!=', 'hcU.nik')
->get();
```